# Custom section in linker script getting ignored

Tags: c, gcc, riscv, linker-scripts

I have following linker script  memory regions in my linker script and T-mem region is where I need to keep my custom section.

```
MEMORY
{
    T-mem (arw!xi)     : ORIGIN =  0x19500000, LENGTH = 0x4000 
     C-mem(arw!xi)     : ORIGIN =  0x19530000, LENGTH = 0x8000 
    STACK(awr!xi)     : ORIGIN =  0x19538000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    INSTR (irx!wa)    : ORIGIN =  0x8abc0000, LENGTH = 0xFF00
    vector_table      : ORIGIN =  0x8abcFF00, LENGTH = 0x100   
}

SECTIONS
{
    .vectors :
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
    } > vector_table
 
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    } >INSTR  

  .tmem : ALIGN(8) {
        PROVIDE(t_mem_load = LOADADDR (.tmem));
        PROVIDE(t_mem_start = .);
        *(.tmem .tmem.*)
        . = ALIGN(8);
        PROVIDE(t_mem_end = .);
     } >tmem AT>INSTR 


    .data : ALIGN(8) {
        PROVIDE(c_mem_load = LOADADDR (.data));
        PROVIDE(c_mem_start = .);
    
        PROVIDE( __global_pointer$ = . + 0x800 );
        *(.sdata .sdata.* .sdata2.*)
        *(.data .data.*)
         . = ALIGN(8);
         PROVIDE(c_mem_end = .);

        
    } >C-Mem AT> INSTR
}
```

And I have created below function to placed in C code.

```
#define TMEM_SEC_FUNC  __attribute__((__section__(".tmem")))

void  TMEM_SEC_FUNC   test_code_for_tmem(){     
    var_h = var_g+0x0A0A0F0F;   
    *(uint32_t volatile *)I_BASE_ADDR = var_h;
}
```

But the above code is always skipped by the GCC compiler . if use #pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
then above code section  is generated in ELF else every time its ignored. Please let me know if any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Try `KEEP(*(.tmem .tmem.*))`. Are you calling this function anywhere?

Comment: Compare `} >tmem AT>INSTR ` with `} >C-Mem AT> INSTR`. If one works and the other one doesn't, I'd ask myself what's different between those two.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks i tried using KEEP((.tmem .tmem.)) it idid not help. yes i am calling this function then i have tried following code #define TMEM_SEC_FUNC __attribute__((__section__(".tmem"))) #define NO_INLINE_FUNC __attribute__((noinline)) void NO_INLINE_FUNC TMEM_SEC_FUNC test_code_for_tmem(){ var_h = var_g+0x0A0A0F0F; *(uint32_t volatile *)I_BASE_ADDR = var_h; } Then it started working . For Some reason i think when O3 optimizing is set GCC will ignore the section if its small code and merge it into text section. So adding noinline helped